# Automatically answer “yes” to a prompt in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, windows-scripting

New to PowerShell scripting. I am trying to run the following code in PowerShell and make a script out of it:

```
md c:\\HWID
Set-Location c:\\HWID
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
Install-Script -Name Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo -Force
Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo.ps1 -OutputFile AutoPilotHWID.csv
```

Problem is I get multiple prompts to either say yes, yes to all, no, no to all, etc. I have tried ECHO, \force, -force, -Confirm:$false, yet I keep getting prompts. I am getting a prompt for NuGet provider. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As an aside: ``\`` has no special meaning in PowerShell, so there's no need to escape it as ``\\``; e.g., `c:\HWID` will do.

Comment: Thanks for updating. In addition to potentially needing `Set-PSRepository -Name PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted`, as shown in the answer below, you may need `Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -Force`, per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/installing-psget?view=powershell-7.3#installing-the-latest-version-of-powershellget

Answer (score 0):

Tested it on new win server 2019 VM.

In case you have a new machine installed,to avoid interruption,
run once from powershell terminal or insert into your script this line:
`Set-PSRepository -Name "PSGallery" -InstallationPolicy Trusted`

```
mkdir c:\HWID2\
Set-Location c:\HWID2\

Set-PSRepository -Name "PSGallery" -InstallationPolicy Trusted # run once
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
Install-Script -Name Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo -Force
...
```

Script does not prompt anymore.